# Use of rank theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $$|rank(P)-rank(Q)|^2=(rank(P)-rank(Q))^2=rank(P)^2-2(rank(P))(rank(Q))+rank(Q)^2$$
$$|rank(P)-rank(Q)|^2\le |rank(P)|^2+2|rank(P)||rank(Q)|+|rank(Q)|^2$$
$$|rank(P)-rank(Q)|^2\le |rank(P)|+|rank(Q)|$$
Since, $rank(P)\ge 0$ and $rank(Q)\ge 0$
$$|rank(P)-rank(Q)|^2\le rank(P)+rank(Q)$$
I'm stuck here and I'm sure if my proof thus far is correct since we know that
$$rank(P+Q)\le rank(P)+rank(Q)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say that your proof is on the right track. I would suggest that you instead use the fact (or try to prove yourself) that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(P + Q) \leq \operatorname{rank}(P) + \operatorname{rank}(Q).
$$
Now, if we set $P = A + B$ and $Q = -B$ and note that $\operatorname{rank}(B) = \operatorname{rank}(-B)$, we find that
$$
\operatorname{rank}((A + B) - B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A + B) + \operatorname{rank}(-B) \implies\\
\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A + B) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \implies\\
\operatorname{rank}(A) - \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A + B).
$$
Now, if we do the same thing but reverse the roles of $A$ and $B$, we end up with
$$
\operatorname{rank}(B) - \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A + B).
$$
Putting these two results together gives us the desired inequality
$$
|\operatorname{rank}(A) - \operatorname{rank}(B)| \leq \operatorname{rank}(A + B).
$$